# Scrape with "load more" button JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

I'm trying to scrape a website with load more button, but I can't do a recursive function with in nightmare. my code is something like this:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({
 show:true
});// }
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

let url = 'https://www.housers.com/es/proyectos/avanzado';
let propertyArray = [];

var getThePage = function() {

     nightmare
      .goto('https://www.housers.com/es/proyectos/avanzado')
      .wait(1500)
      .click('#loadMore')
      .evaluate(() =>{
         return document.querySelector('.all-info').innerHTML;
       })
     .end()
     .then((result) => {
        let $ = cheerio.load(result);
        let loadMore = $('#loadMore')
        if (loadMore) {
            getThePage();
        }
        return result
        })
       .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });
        }
    getThePage()
```

I don't know if you have any way to do it by this method or any other idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scrap the data in the table, you don't need to use nightmare. From the network tab, you would see that it calls this endpoint :

```
https://www.housers.com/es/proyectos/avanzado/scroll
```

with some pagination & page size, let's take 200 per page (don't know if it's above the limit).

Then you just have to parse html & put data in an array :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const entities = require("entities");

const url = 'https://www.housers.com/es/proyectos/avanzado/scroll';

const prices = [];

function doRequest(url, page){
  return axios.post(url + '?page=' + page + '&size=200', querystring.stringify({
    word: "",
    country: "",
    type: "",
    order: "STOCK_PRICE_VARIATION",
    orderDirection: "DESC"
  }));
}

async function getPrices() {
  var empty = false;
  var page = 0;

  while (!empty) {
    //call API
    console.log("GET page n°" + page);
    var res = await doRequest(url, page);
    page++;

    //parse HTML
    const $ = cheerio.load(res.data,{ 
      xmlMode: true,
      normalizeWhitespace: true,
      decodeEntities: true
    });

    if (res.data.trim() !== ""){
      //extract prices : put it in array
      $('tr').map(function(){
        var obj = [];
        $(this).children('td').map(function(){
          obj.push(entities.decodeHTML($(this).text().trim()));
        });
        prices.push(obj);
      });
    }
    else {
      empty = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(prices);
  console.log("total length : " + prices.length);
}

getPrices();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to clarify more I checked in the browser and inside the network "dev bar", and it's possible to check for the requests to the webesite; even if it's infinite scroll or load more button it shows the call to the domain so no needed of looking for selectors.